# Android actionbar : Add divider between 2 menu icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I would like to add a thin divider between my 2 menu item :

[image]

Like Instagram app for example :

[image]

Here is the code of my menu.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_reload"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_reload"
          android:title="Rafraichir"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_more"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
          android:title="A propos"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Comment: you can use ActionBar Sherlock..

Comment: Not supported by default, use a custom view?

Comment: For those suggesting to use ActionBarSherlock, have a read of [this](http://jakewharton.com/deprecated-from-inception/) first and decide if you should.